# Evangelist Prestige class and save progression

Tags: pathfinder-1e, saving-throw

The Evangelist Prestige class level 2 feature, Aligned Class (Ex) states as follows:

> Evangelists come from many different backgrounds, and they show an unusual range of diversity. At 2nd level, the evangelist must choose a class she belonged to before adding the prestige class to be her aligned class. She gains all the class features for this class, essentially adding every evangelist level beyond 1st to her aligned class to determine what class features she gains. **She still retains the Hit Dice, base attack bonus, saving throw bonuses, and skill ranks of the prestige class**, but gains all other class features of her aligned class as well as those of the evangelist prestige class. *(emphasis mine)*

I cannot understand one part. Suppose I am a 5th level Bloodrager, and from 6th level onwards I take levels in the Evangelist Prestige class.

Once I get to level 15 (bloodrager 5/evangelist 10) I'd go back to being a Bloodrager for the last 5 character levels.

My problem is, for the first 15 levels I add the save progression of bloodrager (*class and character levels 1 through 5*) to the one of Evangelist (*class levels 1 to 10, character levels 6 to 15*).
When I level up to 16th level, which level of the bloodrager saves do I add? Do I start counting up from Bloodrager 14 (on account of Aligned Class) or from bloodrager 6 (since I'm not **actually** gaining bloodrager levels, just the relevant class features)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You add your saves starting from where you left off.

You may have the abilities of a level 15 Bloodrager, but your *actual* Bloodrager level is still only 6. You would use the base saves of a level 6 Bloodrager of +5/+2/+2, and add them to your Evangelist 10 saves of +3/+5/+3, for a total of +7/+7/+5 base saves.

In essence, the Evangelist class treats you as being a particular level in a class for the purposes of determining the strength of all class features except for the Hit Die, BAB, Base Save, and Skill Points features, which you calculate based on your levels in that class alone, rather than your levels in that class plus your levels in Evangelist.

Comment: That was my impression as well, can you perchance cite a definite source on that? I've seen quite a bit of debate whether levels counted as class features or not

Comment: @Autongnosis Levels in a class are, by definition, not class features. Levels in a class determine which of the features of that class you get, and how strong those features are. In essence, the Evangelist class treats you as being a particular level in a class for the purposes of determining the strength of all class features except for the Hit Die, BAB, Base Save, and Skill Points features, which you calculate based on your levels in that class alone, rather than your levels in that class plus your levels in Evangelist.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for clarifying